# How to change checkbox attribut 'checked'?

Tags: jquery, html

I have some web page with input fields in it and one of them is a checkbox, I'm trying to create 'clear all' button to clear all values including checkbox 'v'.
I tried `$('#check5').removeAttr('checked');` and `$('#check5').attr('checked',false);`.

But it works only after pressing F5, and I would like to change the attribute status without refreshing the page. Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate as mentioned by @ankitsuthar. Good detail guide is given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
$('#check5').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to remove the 'checked' state from all checkboxes:

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/Vj6wY/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

The checked attribute is a property, try using this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
```

this will make all checkbox's on a page unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

**To uncheck:**

```
$('#check5').prop('checked',false);
```

**To check:**

```
$('#check5').prop('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming at the specific checkbox,

```
$('#check5').prop('checked',false);
```

If not, below given resets all the checkboxes in the page.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

following code is working for me.

```
$(':input').not(':button, :submit').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

It clear all the input type fields inside form.